# How to check if the AlbumArt exists?

Tags: java, android, artwork

I have some Music-Files and some have an artwork and some not.

I use their Uri to load them but I don't know how to check if the Artwork is available or not!

The Uri I have:

```
public Uri getAlbumArtworkUri(long AlbumID) {
        Uri ArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArtworkUri, AlbumID);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in another way...

The Library Picasso for instance has a method called ".placeholder()".

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(AlbumUri).placeholder(standard-/placeholder-image).resize(Width, Height).into(ImageView);
```

Comment: placeholder is not working on notification image, what should I do??